# Converting from C Loop to MIPS assembly language (bad address error)

Tags: c, assembly, mips, spim

I am writing a simple MIPS assembly code that iterates through characters of a string

and finds an instance of a given substring..

First, the c code:

```
for (i=0; i<length(text)-length(sub_string); i++) {

    match = TRUE

    for (j=0; j<length(sub_string); j++)
        if (text[i+j] != sub_string[j]) {
            match = False;
            break;
        }
}
```

And this is part of my MIPS code.

```
.text

# a0: text
# a1: substring
# v0: count
myfunction:
    move $s0, $ra

    move $a2, $a0
    jal  strlen
    move $t1, $v1           # text_len

    move $a2, $a1
    jal  strlen
    move $t2, $v1           # substring_len

    sub  $t1, $t1, $t2      # text_len - substring_len

    li   $t0, 0             # i = 0

    j i_test



i_body:
    li $t3, 1    # match = TRUE
    li $t4, 0    # j = 0

    j j_test

i_test:
    blt $t0, $t1, i_body
    move $ra, $s0
    jr $ra



j_body:
    add $t6, $a0, $t0       # &text[i]
    add $t6, $t6, $t4       # &text[i+j]
    lb  $t6, 0($t6)         # text[i+j]

    add $t7, $a1, $t4       # &sub_string[j]
    lb  $t7, 0($t7)         # sub_string[j]

    beq $t6, $t7, j_skip    # if (text[i+j] == sub_string[j])

    # if (text[i+j] != sub_string[j])
    li  $t3, 0              # match = FALSE
    j   j_break             # break

j_test:
    blt $t4, $t2, j_body

j_skip:
    addi $t4, $t4, 1    # j++
    j    j_body

j_break:
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    # i++
    j    i_body



strlen:
    li $v1, 0           # i = 0
    b strlen_test
strlen_body:
    addi $v1, $v1, 1    # len++
strlen_test:
    add $t0, $a2, $v1           # &str[i]
    lb $t0, 0($t0)              # str[i]
    bne $t0, $0, strlen_body    # loop
    jr $ra




.globl main
main:

    la $a0, text1
    la $a1, substring1
    jal myfunction
    la $a0, text1
    jal print_string

    li  $v0, 10         # Exit
    syscall


print_string: 
          li    $v0, 4
          syscall
          la    $a0, newline
          li    $v0, 4
          syscall
          jr    $ra


.data
text1:      .asciiz "Hello, world!"
substring1: .asciiz "lo"

newline:    .asciiz "\n"
```

However, when I run this code, I am getting this infinite loop of bad

address errors:

```
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400070                                                 
Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10021778                                                                                                                           
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored                                                                                                    
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400078                                                                                                                                      
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10021786                                                                                                                             
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored                                                                                                    
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400070                                                                                                                                      
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10021779                                                                                                                             
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored                                                                                                    
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400078                                                                                                                                      
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10021787                                                                                                                             
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored                                                                                                    
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400070                                                                                                                                      
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x1002177a                                                                                                                             
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored                                                                                                    
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400078                                                                                                                                      
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10021788                                                                                                                             
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored                                                                                                    
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400070                                                                                                                                      
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x1002177b                                                                                                                            
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored                                                                                                    
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400078                                                                                                                                      
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10021789                                                                                                                             
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored
```

I realized the bad address error is coming from the 3rd and 5th lines of

j_body (the load byte instructions). I've initialized the string address, so I am not sure why this is

happening...

Here are my questions:

1. Why am I getting this infinite loop? 
   (I thought I've implemented the for loops for i and j correctly)
2. Why am I getting a bad address error??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
j_test:
    blt $t4, $t2, j_body

j_skip:
    addi $t4, $t4, 1    # j++
    j    j_body

j_break:
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    # i++
    j    i_body
```

Shouldn't you be jumping to `j_break` if the condition for `j_test` fails? The way this code is written right now you proceed with executing the body of the "j loop" even if `j >= strlen(substring)`.

Also, the `j i_body` after `j_break:` should probably be `j i_test` (you've increased `i`, so you'll want to check if condition for the "i loop" still is true).

Comment: changing j i_body to j i_test solved my problem :))))) you're the best!!

Answer (score 1):

In j_body, you use $t7 both to store str(i+j), and sub_str(j); then decide whether to exit j_body by comparing beq $t7, $t7, j_body (this instruction alone would anyway always evaluate true, and make this an infinite loop). Store the byte from sub_str(j) in $t8, and change the beq line to comparing $t7 and $t8.

There might be more; but this definitely must change. After you correct this, I suggest run, and update your question with any new errors you get.

Comment: awww sorry :( That was a typo... Now I'm comparing $t6 and $t7, but getting the same infinite errors. Thanks for pointing out my stupid mistake though

Comment: But now you're not jumping back, in case of equality, to j_body (j_skip instead). I think jumping to j_body was right, minus the typo.

Comment: Also, @Michael is one of the resident assembly guys, so probably also adjust for what he found.